# Can statvfs block on certain network devices? How to handle that case?

Tags: c++, c, networking, disk

I am using keybase (a cloud base data store for your SSH and other keys) and today somehow it did not restart when I started X-Windows.

As a result, the command `df` (and thus `statvfs()` in my code) would just block after telling me that the transport was down.

```
$ df
df: '/home/alexis/"/home/alexis/.local/share/keybase/fs"': Transport endpoint is not connected
df: /run/user/1000/gvfs: Transport endpoint is not connected
_
```

The prompt would sit there and never return.

I don't care much that `df` would get stuck at the moment, but I'm wondering how I should update my C++ code to handle the case where `statvfs()` blocks in my application because that's not acceptable there. I just don't see a way to break out of that call without using a signal (SIGALRM comes to mind).

Is there a better way to handle this case?

(Note: my code is in C++, although a C solution should work just fine and is likely what is required, hence the tagging with both languages.)

Comment: Is your application single-threaded?  You'd have to install your `SIGALARM` handler without the default `SA_RESTART`, and there's likely a lot of other code that would break if you did that throughout your entire application.  And if you're multithreaded, you risk breaking other threads anyway.

Comment: @AndrewHenle It's single threaded. Easiest way to make sure it does not break all over the place... Also it's a short lived fork()-ed process. I suppose the `SA_RESTART` would restart the `statvfs()`... which thus would continue blocking. Hmmm...

Comment: If your process is single-threaded, just use `sigaction()` to install a signal handler for `SIGALARM` *without* the `SA_RESTART` flag, so the alarm will cause `statvfs()` to fail with `errno` set to `EINTR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will wrap `statvfs()` in a function that sets up an alarm to interrupt the call.  It will return `-1` with errno set to `EINTR` should the alarm fire and interrupt the call to `statvfs()` (I haven't tried this so it may not be perfect...):

```
#include <sigaction.h>
#include <sys/statvfs.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

// alarm handler doesn't need to do anything
// other than simply exist
static void alarm_handler( int sig )
{
    return;
}

 .
 .
 .

// statvfs() with a timeout measured in seconds
// will return -1 with errno set to EINTR should
// it time out
int statvfs_try( const char *path, struct statvfs *s, unsigned int seconds )
{
    struct sigaction newact;
    struct sigaction oldact;

    // make sure they're entirely clear (yes I'm paranoid...)
    memset( &newact, 0, sizeof( newact ) );
    memset( &oldact, 0, sizeof( oldact) );

    sigemptyset( &newact.sa_mask );

    // note that does not have SA_RESTART set, so
    // statvfs should be interrupted on a signal
    // (hopefully your libc doesn't restart it...)
    newact.sa_flags = 0;
    newact.sa_handler = alarm_handler;
    sigaction( SIGALRM, &newact, &oldact );

    alarm( seconds );

    // clear errno
    errno = 0;
    int rc = statvfs( path, s );

    // save the errno value as alarm() and sigaction() might change it
    int save_errno = errno;

    // clear any alarm and reset the signal handler
    alarm( 0 );
    sigaction( SIGALRM, &oldact, NULL );

    errno = saved_errno;
    return( rc );
}
```

That could also use some error checking, especially on the `sigaction()` calls, but it's long enough to generate a scroll bar already, so I left that out.

If you find your process remains stuck in `statvfs()` call, and if you're running on Linux, run your process under the `strace` and trace the actual system calls.  You should see the call to `statvfs()`, then an alarm signal that interrupts the `statvfs()` call.  If you see *another* call to `statvfs()`, that means your `libc` has restarted the system call.